# 1955 Miklós Schweitzer Problem 3 - concentration inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, contest-math

**Source**: 1955 Miklós Schweitzer [Problem 3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1147098p5413645)

> Let the density function $f(x)$ of a random variable $\xi$ be an even function; let further $f(x)$ be monotonically non-increasing for $x > 0$. Suppose that
> $$D^2= \int_\mathbb{R} x^2 f(x)\;dx$$
> exists. Prove that for $\lambda > 0$,
> $$P(\left|\xi\right| \geq \lambda D)\leq \frac{1}{1+\lambda^2}.$$

**Attempt**: As $f(\cdot)$ is even, $\mathbb{E}(\xi)=0$. I apply Cantelli's inequality to obtain

$$P(|\xi| \geq \lambda D)\leq \frac{2}{1+\lambda^2}.$$

Well, I guess it wasn't meant to be that easy haha... so I assume I must do something using monotonicity of $f(\cdot)$. Alternatively, I wanted to apply some exponential tail bound - for instance ideally yielding something similar to the following:

$$P(|\xi| \geq \lambda D)\leq^* e^{-g(\lambda)}\leq \frac{1}{1+\lambda^2},$$

where $\leq^*$ would follow by showing $\xi$ is sub-Gamma/Gaussian/etc. but I didn't put much thought into this approach.

**Question**: Is there a way to just slightly change the initial lazy approach I took - i.e. maybe another concentration inequality in a clever way? Or is the approach totally different? I appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: If you put 아ppreciate into google you go back to this question.

Comment: ㅋㅋㅋㅋ - fixed now thanks ;)

Comment: Perhaps Chebyshev will help

Comment: It gives $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ as an upper bound which doesn't help. Are you maybe suggesting to relate this to the one-sided version of Chebyshev's? To be honest, I see no way of doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use the Camp-Meidell inequality ([1], [2]).

If $\lambda < \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$, we have
$$P(|\xi | \ge \lambda D )
\le 1 - \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt 3}
\le \frac{1}{1 + \lambda^2}.$$

If $\lambda \ge \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$, we have
$$P(|\xi | \ge \lambda D )
\le \frac{4}{9\lambda^2}
\le \frac{1}{1 + \lambda^2}.$$

We are done.

*References*.

[1] https://vrs20.amsi.org.au/wp-content/uploads/sites/75/2020/01/hanna_matthew_vrs-report.pdf

[2] Thomas M. Sellke and Sarah H. Sellke, “Chebyshev Inequalities for Unimodal Distributions,” The American Statistician
Vol. 51, No. 1 (Feb., 1997), pp. 34-40 (7 pages).
https://www.jstor.org/page-scan-delivery/get-page-scan/2684690/0

Comment: Wow… beautiful thanks - I had to run through the proof as I haven’t heard of it before - it is definitely the way to expand my initial lazy approach

Comment: @pSrIoGcNeAsLs You are welcome. I guess the official solution (if any) does not apply the Camp-Meidell inequality. Perhaps there is some approach to use $$P\Big(g(|\xi|/D) \ge g(\lambda)\Big) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}(g(|\xi|/D))}{g(\lambda)}$$ for some $g(\cdot)$.